# Can you see if a person has read your message in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Can I check or see if the recipient has read the message I sent them?

Where in Facebook do I go to see if this is possible?

Comment: basically no you cant see if the person you sent it to has read it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From now on, [yes](https://www.facebook.com/help/316575021742112/#How-do-I-know-if-a-friend-has-seen-a-message-I-sent). Facebook provides *Read Receipts* for its users.

> **How do I know if a friend has seen a message I sent?**
>
> When someone sees your most recent message, it will be marked as seen.
>   That way, you always know who got the message, and who didn't.
>
> [image]
>
> Messages are marked as seen if the person is actively chatting or
>   checking their messages.
>
> This feature is part of every message you send, whether it's from your
>   phone or the web.

Comment: actually facebook has changed this, see answer by galacticninja below.

Comment: @don el ka nal: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible. FB messages are not even email, and even with email nowadays return receipts are not really widespread outside of corporate mania.

Comment: If you have been rolled over to the new service http://www.facebook.com/about/messages/ you can use it as email.

Comment: @phwd: wow! did not know that, just signed up!

Comment: New service meaning the timeline? Please clarify

Comment: @LORI at the time being the new service was Messages but this has been rolled out to everyone by now. You still cannot use read receipts but Messages are very much like email. *Just not email*

Comment: I think that now you can: https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=316575021742112#How-do-I-know-if-a-friend-has-seen-a-message-I-sent?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you [now can (Facebook Help Center link)](https://www.facebook.com/help/316575021742112/#How-do-I-know-if-a-friend-has-seen-a-message-I-sent). Just go to your message inbox; you should see the notification at the bottom of your message.

[image]

Related Web Apps SE questions:
[How to disable "Seen by" in Facebook chat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27355/how-to-disable-seen-by-in-facebook-chat/35931#35931)
[Does "previewing" a Facebook message mark it as Seen?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29922/does-previewing-a-facebook-message-mark-it-as-seen)