# Disabling the “seen message” feature on Facebook when friends send me a message

Tags: facebook, notifications

I want to disable the feature where I actually see that a friend read my message. At times  I think it’s just better if I don’t know whether they’ve seen it or not.

**N.B I am not talking about disabling the feature where when I click on a message they see that I have read it.**

Comment: that's not possible, facebook doesn't allow for that.

Comment: Related - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27355/how-to-disable-seen-by-in-facebook-chat

Answer (score 2):

There are some browser extensions with this function

[Chrome] FB unseen:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ihcedcpmfdpjijiamkaeaefgfagnnpei

[Firefox-userscript] Facebook Stealth:
http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/136261

Or block this url in any adblocker:
facebook.com/ajax/mercury/change_read_status.php

Comment: Thanks for your input however that's not the question I asked, my N.B states **I am not talking about disabling the feature where when I click on a message they see that I have read it.**

Comment: You can hide the text by add this query selector to adblocker: [class*='typingIndicator'][class*='seen'] OR add this CSS to Chrome's User StyleSheets: .seen{display:none !important;}td div.seen{display:none !important;}

Answer (score 0):

You could use an extension such as [StyleBot for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) to hide the HTML element that shows the text. There is an element at the bottom of the chat window with the class `typingIndicator`. This element controls the grey text at the bottom of the chat window, including when someone is typing and when someone has seen your message.

When this element contains a "seen" message, it will have the class `seen`. So, you can make it invisible when this condition is met using the following CSS rule:

```
.typingIndicator.seen { visibility: hidden }
```