# Does "previewing" a Facebook message mark it as Seen?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Say I get a New Message notification (the red box over the Messages icon). I then click on the Messages icon, so I am viewing the "preview" of all of my recent conversations. The red notification icon goes away.

Even if I didn't open the conversation itself to view the full text, does the message get marked as read?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you see text 1/2/3 in a small red cloud in the Envelope icon(Notification) in the top-blue bar & you click that, and preview the message, Message will NOT be marked as read.

To simplify, Until you actually Go to Messages, click that Specific Message and see it in FULL, no message will be marked as Read.

Unread messages always have a faint blue background, whereas read messages have pure white.

Any message can be marked as Unread again, from the screen where you read it.

*TL:DR;* **No, it will not be marked as read.** :)