# If you mark a Facebook message as read, will it show up as "Seen..." to the person who sent it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Even if you don't actually click on the message to open it?

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29922/does-previewing-a-facebook-message-mark-it-as-seen

Answer (score 5):

The moment you click 'mark as read'..it will be notified to the other person as 'seen so and so time' ..I've experimented..no need to doubt..whether you view the message and later mark as unread or you don't view the message at all but simply mark it as read..either way it'll show 'seen' to the other person..

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this myself, I made another account and sent a message from my computer to my phone and as soon as I clicked mark as read on the message on my phone it said 'seen' and the time on my computer. So marking as read still lets the other person know you read their message.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid not. The seen notification only works when you have opened the message.

Comment: Any references you can cite here?

Answer (score -3):

It reverts the time as seen as the moment you wrote it actually

Comment: Can you expand on that a bit? This isn't very useful or descriptive.